# Non-electrical savvy person question

Tags: schematic

[image]I work on commercial food processing equipment. With a schematic, I am somewhat useful but without one I am generally lost.
I just received a German machine that is a dual capacitor start/run machine. The company is no longer in business and documentation is non-existent, with the exception of the one drawing I found after weeks of searching. The problem is the wires were removed from the switch when I received the machine and the switch on the machine is not the same model as the schematic.
I have attached the drawing but I don't understand the switch function. If someone could explain the positions on the switch (I know where power comes in and that common bypasses the [image]switch) but I don't understand the different functions. Thanking you in advance for any help, in this matter.

Answer (score 2):

connecting 2 and 3 will make it run fast in one direction.

connecting 1 and 3  will make it run slow in the opposite direction.

connecting 1,2 and 3 might make it run even faster in the first direction or it might be bad.

Any connection that doesn't include 3 will cause it to stop.

I cannot tell from the diagram which of the above options the original switch provided.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you have any idea where the 25 mfd capacitor on the top connects on the switch. Also, what does the curved line in the switch denote?

Comment: the curved line is probably a wire, without seeing the original switch it's hard to guess.

Comment: Thanks Jasen, Since I have a completely different switch, I am trying to find out which of the wires connect when turned on.  one that I am working on is from a company in Germany that doesn't exist anymore. It's a rotary switch with only two positions off/on. What I need to know is when I turn it on, what wires go hot on the terminal board. This thing has a dual capacitor motor without a centrifugal switch to interrupt the starting capacitor. I am confused as to if both capacitors run all the same time or how the switch with only 2 positions can disable the starting capacitor when turned on.

Comment: are both capacitor physically the same size?

Comment: Yes, they are both the same size and both are 25mfd. They are oil filled and about 6 inches long and 2 inches diameter.

Comment: they are both run capacitors then. there is no starting capacitor.

Comment: Thanks Jasen, I finally decided that the motor was a permanent split capacitor (PSC). I wired the motor last night as 2 run capacitors and it ran correctly. Thank you for your help. I finally found an explanation about motors with starting windings. They have auxiliary and run windings but no start winding.

Comment: Thanks Jasen, I finally decided that the motor was a permanent split capacitor (PSC). I wired the motor last night as a 2-run capacitor motor and it ran correctly. Thank you for your help. I finally found an explanation about motors without start windings. They have auxiliary and run windings but no start winding. What a trip this has been